# Converting .okular file to pdf

Tags: pdf, djvu, okular

I am using a djvu file, and with okular I have annotations in it. Now, I wish to be able to use this file in Mendeley, which supports only pdf extensions. I know that I can save annotations in okular using Export As -> Document Archive. But that is saved with .okular extension. How do I convert it to .pdf?

Answer (score 3):

From [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71584/storing-okular-pdf-annotations-and-metadata-in-the-pdf-itself) and by extension the [Okular documentation](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html), you should be able to do this using `File` -> `Save As` to save a copy of the annotated document as a PDF.

I quote the relevant part of the documentation:

> Since Okular 0.15 you can also save annotations directly into PDF files. This feature is only available if Okular has been built with version 0.20 or later of Poppler rendering library. You can use File → Save As... to save the copy of PDF file with annotations.

Comment: I have okular version 0.14.3 with KDE 4.8.4. I use deian wheezy and I dont know how I can upgrade to 0.15 version.

Comment: @lepto that would be an entirely different question.

Comment: @ Joseph, is there an easy way to upgrade okular from 0.14.3 to >0.15?

Comment: @lepto Short answer: switch your repos to testing and upgrade `okular` or download the `okular` 0.15 source and build it yourself, but I still maintain that you need to ask this in a separate question.